# Двоеточие после "к тому же"

Tags: пунктуация

Весь оковалок текста можно не читать - только глянуть начало-кончало цитаты (отобразившейся с дырками, не задуманными автором).

Это - начало абзаца!

> **К тому же:** «должностные лица, которые управляли провинциями от имени
>   императоров или сената и которым вверено было исключительное право
>   суда над уголовными преступниками, большей частью вели себя как люди
>   благовоспитанные и образованные, уважающие требования справедливости и
>   знакомые с принципами философии. Нередко случалось, что они отклоняли
>   от себя отвратительную роль гонителей, с презрением отвергали
>   обвинение или научали подсудимых христиан какой-нибудь легальной
>   увёртке, с помощью которой можно было избежать строгости законов.
>   Всякий раз, когда они бывали облечены неограниченной властью, они
>   употребляли ее не столько на угнетение, сколько на облегчение и пользу
>   страждущей церкви. Они были далеки от того, чтоб присуждать к
>   наказанию всякого христианина, уличенного в упорной привязанности к
>   новому суеверию. Большей частью ограничиваясь менее жестокими
>   наказаниями — тюремным заключением, ссылкой или невольнической
>   работой в рудниках, они оставляли несчастным жертвам своего
>   правосудия некоторую надежду, что какое-нибудь счастливое событие —
>   восшествие нового императора на престол, его вступление
>   в брак или военный триумф, — возвратят им, путем всеобщей амнистии,
>   их прежнее положение. Те мученики, которых римские судьи обрекали на
>   немедленную казнь, как кажется, выбирались из двух самых
>   противоположных разрядов обвиняемых. Или это были епископы
>    и пресвитеры, то есть такие люди, которые были самые выдающиеся между
>   христианами по своему положению и влиянию и примерное наказание
>   которых могло наводить ужас на всю секту; или же это были самые низкие
>   и самые презренные члены секты, и в особенности рабы, так как их жизнь
>   ценилась очень низко, а на их страдания смотрели с чрезмерным
>   равнодушием», — так описывает этот исторический феномен Эдвард
>   Гиббон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К тому же "должностные лица, которые управляли провинциями от имени императоров или сената и которым вверено было исключительное право суда над уголовными преступниками, большей частью вели себя как люди благовоспитанные и образованные, уважающие требования справедливости и знакомые с принципами философии". "Нередко случалось, что они отклоняли от себя отвратительную роль гонителей, с презрением отвергали обвинение или научали подсудимых христиан какой-нибудь легальной увёртке, с помощью которой можно было избежать строгости законов. Всякий раз, когда они бывали облечены неограниченной властью, они употребляли ее не столько на угнетение, сколько на облегчение и пользу страждущей церкви. Они были далеки от того, чтоб присуждать к наказанию всякого христианина, уличенного в упорной привязанности к новому суеверию. Большей частью ограничиваясь менее жестокими наказаниями — тюремным заключением, ссылкой или невольнической работой в рудниках, они оставляли несчастным жертвам своего правосудия некоторую надежду, что какое-нибудь счастливое событие — восшествие нового императора на престол, его вступление в брак или военный триумф, — возвратят им, путем всеобщей амнистии, их прежнее положение. Те мученики, которых римские судьи обрекали на немедленную казнь, как кажется, выбирались из двух самых противоположных разрядов обвиняемых. Или это были епископы  и пресвитеры, то есть такие люди, которые были самые выдающиеся между христианами по своему положению и влиянию и примерное наказание которых могло наводить ужас на всю секту; или же это были самые низкие и самые презренные члены секты, и в особенности рабы, так как их жизнь ценилась очень низко, а на их страдания смотрели с чрезмерным равнодушием» — так описывает этот исторический феномен Эдвард Гиббон. (Последней запятой  не должно быть.)

Либо:

"Должностные лица, которые управляли провинциями от имени императоров или сената и которым вверено было исключительное право суда над уголовными преступниками, большей частью вели себя как люди благовоспитанные и образованные, уважающие требования справедливости и знакомые с принципами философии. Нередко случалось, что они отклоняли от себя отвратительную роль гонителей, с презрением отвергали обвинение или научали подсудимых христиан какой-нибудь легальной увёртке, с помощью которой можно было избежать строгости законов. Всякий раз, когда они бывали облечены неограниченной властью, они употребляли ее не столько на угнетение, сколько на облегчение и пользу страждущей церкви. Они были далеки от того, чтоб присуждать к наказанию всякого христианина, уличенного в упорной привязанности к новому суеверию. Большей частью ограничиваясь менее жестокими наказаниями — тюремным заключением, ссылкой или невольнической работой в рудниках, они оставляли несчастным жертвам своего правосудия некоторую надежду, что какое-нибудь счастливое событие — восшествие нового императора на престол, его вступление в брак или военный триумф, — возвратят им, путем всеобщей амнистии, их прежнее положение. Те мученики, которых римские судьи обрекали на немедленную казнь, как кажется, выбирались из двух самых противоположных разрядов обвиняемых. Или это были епископы  и пресвитеры, то есть такие люди, которые были самые выдающиеся между христианами по своему положению и влиянию и примерное наказание которых могло наводить ужас на всю секту; или же это были самые низкие и самые презренные члены секты, и в особенности рабы, так как их жизнь ценилась очень низко, а на их страдания смотрели с чрезмерным равнодушием» — так описывает этот исторический феномен Эдвард Гиббон.

Comment: "Последней запятой не должно быть", - прозевала, мерсю.